# Sql Server user login for a Web Application

Tags: sql-server, security, web-applications, iis-7.5, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm want to create a SQl Server login for a IIS web application. Since the Web Application using IIS 7.5 identity, and in addition in production the Sql Server may be in a separate machine, I'm looking for use a user and password based connection string.

Now, I'm a little confused how to create this login in Sql Server 2008 R2. Should I use databawse specific User, or a global login? Should I Database Role or Application Role?

What are the best practices to get a login for an IIS application that don't use Stored Procedures, but makes a use of an ORM tool, like NHibernate?

Answer (score 1):

The following article:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb882673.aspx

recommends using Integrated Security to connect to the database.

Comment: Does Integrated Security useful when the Sql Server is on a separate computer on the cluster?

Comment: If they are on the same domain then yes